# Why is it necessary to refresh page in order to be authenticated?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I've built an authentication flow with an access token everything is working so far. But one think is strange and kind of destroys the whole auth. flow. When I log in with user, I first don't have access to the data due to my token, I am in the app though, but I don't have my authenticated data there. So I need to refresh the page and then I get the data and I'm authenticated. Thats also an issue when I'm logging in with a different user, because then I get the data of the last user, and when I log in with a next user I get the data of the last user and so on. It seems like its always one behind and I have no idea why...
Here is my code.

auth.service

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
...

export const TOKEN_KEY = 'access_token';
export const USERNAME_KEY = 'username_key';
export const USER_ID = 'user_id';
export const REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY = 'refresh_token';

 user = null;
  refreshToken = null;
  authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject(false);



   constructor(private http: HttpClient, private storage: Storage, private helper: JwtHelperService) {
      this.checkToken();
   }

   checkToken() {
       this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY).then(access => {
           if (access) {
               this.user = this.helper.decodeToken(access);
               this.authenticationState.next(true);
           }
       });
   }

   validateId(user_id: any): number {
    return parseInt(user_id);
}

 apilogin(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.url}/api/token/`, { username, password })
    .pipe(
        tap(res => {
            this.storage.set(TOKEN_KEY, res['access']);
            this.storage.set(USERNAME_KEY, username);
            this.storage.set(USER_ID, this.user['user_id']);
            this.user = this.helper.decodeToken(res['access']);
            console.log('my user: ', this.user);
            this.authenticationState.next(true);
        })
   );
}

apilogout() {
    this.storage.remove(USER_ID);
    this.storage.remove(REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY);
    this.storage.remove(USERNAME_KEY);
    this.storage.remove(TOKEN_KEY).then(() => {
    this.authenticationState.next(false);
   });
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IonicStorageModule, Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { JwtModule, JWT_OPTIONS} from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

export function jwtOptionsFactory(storage) {
  return {
    tokenGetter: () => {
      return storage.get('access_token');
    },
    whitelistedDomains: ['localhost']
  };

}

@NgModule({
 ...
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      jwtOptionsProvider: {
        provide: JWT_OPTIONS,
        useFactory: jwtOptionsFactory,
        deps: [Storage]
       }
    }) ],

...
}
```

user.ts

```
...

  information = null;
  id: number;
  key: string;

  constructor(private router: Router, private storage: Storage, private userService: UserService, private authService: AuthService) { }

...

  ngOnInit() {
    // How to get just the authenticated api?
      if (this.authService.authenticationState) {
      this.storage.get(USER_ID).then(val => {
        this.id = val;
        console.log(this.id);
        this.userService.getUserDetails(this.id).subscribe(result => {
          this.information = result;
          console.log(this.information);
        });
      });
    }

    }
```

Comment: What's `storage`? Also, your auth service is missing some info (constructor, class declaration etc)

Comment: added. Auth service is just a normal `export class {}` . I've also added a page where I get my view, if that helps. But its the same for all pages I get data only the owner of the account can see.